# AppEngine Error [ java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/ElementTraversal ]

Tags: google-app-engine

i was looking to find a solution for this problem but seems difficult. I have appengine project working with a servlet that handle registration. When i try to call this servlet i have this log report:

```
012-04-19 10:31:06.816 /register 500 90ms 0kb Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)
ip - gecodroidtest [19/Apr/2012:10:31:06 -0700] "POST /register HTTP/1.1" 500 0 - "Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)" "cloudnotifyit.appspot.com" ms=90 cpu_ms=58 api_cpu_ms=0 cpm_usd=0.001738 instance=00c61b117c772731eb45290bfcb07750c0505f
W 2012-04-19 10:31:06.794
com.cloudnotify.server.servlet.RequestInfo processRequest: xxxxxxxxxxxx@xxxx  //just for me
W 2012-04-19 10:31:06.810
Error for /register 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/ElementTraversal
    at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-240c2ffe1bf8ddba(Request.java)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractDOMParser.startDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.startEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.startDocumentParsing(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:121)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.readNamedPMFProperties(JDOHelper.java:1407)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getNamedPMFProperties(JDOHelper.java:1286)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPropertiesFromJdoconfig(JDOHelper.java:1232)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:1079)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:914)
    at com.cloudnotify.server.c2dm.C2DMessaging.getPMF(C2DMessaging.java:103)
    at com.cloudnotify.server.servlet.RequestInfo.initDevices(RequestInfo.java:225)
    at com.cloudnotify.server.servlet.RequestInfo.processRequest(RequestInfo.java:183)
    at com.cloudnotify.server.servlet.RegisterServlet.doPost(RegisterServlet.java:100)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:449)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:455)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:695)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:333)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:325)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:453)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.w3c.dom.ElementTraversal
    at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-240c2ffe1bf8ddba(Request.java)
    ... 44 more
C 2012-04-19 10:31:06.812
Uncaught exception from servlet
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/ElementTraversal
    at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-240c2ffe1bf8ddba(Request.java)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractDOMParser.startDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.startEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.startDocumentParsing(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:121)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.readNamedPMFProperties(JDOHelper.java:1407)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getNamedPMFProperties(JDOHelper.java:1286)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPropertiesFromJdoconfig(JDOHelper.java:1232)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:1079)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:914)
    at com.cloudnotify.server.c2dm.C2DMessaging.getPMF(C2DMessaging.java:103)
    at com.cloudnotify.server.servlet.RequestInfo.initDevices(RequestInfo.java:225)
    at com.cloudnotify.server.servlet.RequestInfo.processRequest(RequestInfo.java:183)
    at com.cloudnotify.server.servlet.RegisterServlet.doPost(RegisterServlet.java:100)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:449)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:455)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:695)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:333)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:325)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:453)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.w3c.dom.ElementTraversal
    at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-240c2ffe1bf8ddba(Request.java)
    ... 44 more


Thanks all
```

Comment: Sharing what I observed............   I got the same exception even when I had xml-apis-1.3.02 in WEB_INF/lib. I just switched to use new version of this jar xml-apis-1.4.01 and it worked fine.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There may be some existing issue with the Xerces parser on GAE.  See  http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1367

Maybe the workaround is to ensure that all of Xerces jars (including xml-apis.jar) are in your WEB-INF/lib.

Comment: Many thanks, including xml-apis.jar in WEB-INF/LIB worked and has solved the problem !

Comment: Yes for some reason Xerces || NekoHtmlParser jar not imported!!

Answer (score 173):

- **MAVEN SOLUTION:**

At pom.xml , set "xml-apis" dependency to version 1.4.01:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.01</version>
</dependency>
```

- **SOLUTION FOR EVERYONE ELSE:**

If not using maven, you can manually add the xml-apis library, version 1.4.01. You will find the jars inside the xml-commons binary package, named "XML Commons External 1.4.01", and you can download it here: http://xerces.apache.org/mirrors.cgi.

Finally, compile and execute your java application/project with this version of the library.

- ***Explanation*:**

The 1.4.01 version of the xml-apis library, includes the required ElementTraversal class. Other versions like 2.0.0, 1.0.0, etc. do not include it, and the application fails while compiling.

Comment: I had a similar problem with Selenium WebDriver.  Adding xml-apis to the project fixed it.  Thanks.

Comment: Tomcat 7 maven plugin had the same issue, after i added the xml-apis dependency it seem to work fine

Comment: Seems 2.0.2 version is released with incorrect version accidentally, and they later moved that release to correct version. See http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xml-apis/xml-apis/2.0.2 (2.0.2 released in 2002, but most recent correct 1.4.01 is released in 2009)

Comment: I have no experience with Maven so I don't know what to do with the xml file. But I just added the xml-apis.jar to my NetBeans Project and that solved the issue. I faced this problem while using Apache ODF toolkit.

Comment: had this problem while reading xlsx via APACHE POI . xml-apis version 1.4.01 solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

Your issue can be resolved by updating to version [2.11.0.SP5](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xerces/xercesImpl/2.11.0.SP5), which already contains the class `ElementTraversal`.