# Eclipse java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/ElementTraversal

Tags: eclipse

I am using eclipse juno.. when i opening javascript file in eclipse it returns the error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/ElementTraversal
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
```

how can i overcome this..

Comment: do you have web tools platform installed?

Comment: ya when i opening first time it returns that error ....after the continuous opening opens the file in black letters(that means there is no difference coloring and all elements in black color)

Comment: have you tried with a clean install of Eclipse?

Comment: are you sure you have javascript developer tools (for sure) in and/or are not missing any library?

Comment: here is a related question on the eclipse forum, maybe it will help:http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/889148/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AppEngine Error \[ java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/ElementTraversal \]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10234201/appengine-error-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-w3c-dom-elementtraversal)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/51094274/421049. This seem similar to [Eclipse Bug 536928](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=536928). I encourage you to go vote for it so that maybe they will raise its priority and address it.

Comment: @GarretWilson the other thread is specific to Java 9+, while this thread from 2012 must have some other background.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I had an issue when I tried using version `2.0.2`, but found that when I reverted back to version `1.4.01` and everything worked again.

If you're using Maven:

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.01</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: i agree. but does anyone know what the problem is going forward?

Comment: 1.4.01 is the _newest_ version for this lib. As it can be noticed [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xml-apis/xml-apis/2.0.2), 2.0.2 is **prior** to 1.0.b2

Comment: I am coming across this error, i am using selenium webdriver with junit and maven. I have added the dependency but the problem persists. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You need xml-apis. Have a look at this:http://www.coderanch.com/t/534171/XML/org-dom-ElementTraversal