# getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/ElementTraversal exception when running test

Tags: java, spring, maven, junit, spring-security

i'm experiencing an issue with my configuration in a web project.

i've just taken a look at the other answers about this problem, but they didn't work for me.

in my pom i have

```
...
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId> 
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId> 
            <version>5.0.6.Final</version> 
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.6.Final</version> 
        </dependency>                
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>  
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>               
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20151123</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.3</version>
        </dependency>     
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.8</version>
        </dependency>  

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0-b01</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava-collections</artifactId>
            <version>r03</version>
        </dependency>     




        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jresey.version}</version>
        </dependency>                             
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>${jresey.version}</version>
        </dependency>  



        <!-- @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-openid</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>      
        </dependency>

        <!-- security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity-oauth.version}</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- log -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- commons -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>${commonsfileupload.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>${commonslang.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>${httpclient.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.skyscreamer</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsonassert</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
...
```

when runnig test with junit and mockito i get this exception

```
log4j:WARN Error during default initialization
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/ElementTraversal
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractDOMParser.startDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.startEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.startDocumentParsing(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator$2.parse(DOMConfigurator.java:769)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:871)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:778)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:526)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:127)
    at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:104)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.getLogger(Log4JLogger.java:262)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.<init>(Log4JLogger.java:108)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.createLogFromClass(LogFactoryImpl.java:1025)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.discoverLogImplementation(LogFactoryImpl.java:844)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:541)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:292)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:269)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:655)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.<clinit>(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:86)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:29)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:21)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:26)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:250)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.w3c.dom.ElementTraversal
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 62 more
```

if i remove the spring-security-openid dependency, tests work but the application doesn't compile and i get the error

```
COMPILATION ERROR : 
-------------------------------------------------------------
error: com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for org.springframework.security.openid.OpenIDAttribute not found
```

i suppose the problem is in maven dependencies but i was not able to find where it occurs.

I'm using netbeans 8.1 as ide, and a collegue of mine using eclipse doesn't experiences the issue

Could you please give me some suggestion?

thanks

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17515501/280244 -- it is the first hit on google for "org/w3c/dom/ElementTraversal" and the second hit is better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840989/eclipse-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-w3c-dom-elementtraversal

Comment: i just took a look at those answers but they didn't solve my problem... i still have same issue.... i don't know if it could be usefull...i'm using netbeans 8.1 as ide, and a collegue of mine is not experiencing this problems using eclipse ide

Comment: You have a maven pom! - build and test it with maven!! - if it works with maven then you know that this ia an problem with your IDE.

Comment: Hi ralph... that was my first attempt... but even if i build the project with maven (version 3.3.9) from comand line i get the same error...
the strange is that building it in eclipse using same version of maven...it works... so i don't have idea about what is happening

Comment: When I remember right, the problem is, that eclipse is not able not correctly handle all maven dependency scopes.

Comment: You have just added in that "the other answers didn't work". I would like you to edit in what you attempted to do (e.g. I replaced x with y) and what the result was (e.g. my computer exploded, which is not what I wanted). Without this, it is hard to tell how your question is different from the duplicate.

Comment: ok Samurai8...i will keep in mind for future questions.

About current issue we solved adding explicit xerces dependency in our pom. This dependency is required by spring-security-openid  but resolved at runtime