# The package com.google.inject is accessible from more than one module

Tags: java, eclipse, guice, java-platform-module-system

I'm trying to upgrade an application to Java 11.0.2, from Java 8. So those are my very first steps with Jigsaw modules!

My application uses [Guice](https://github.com/google/guice), and the `Assistedinject`, and `Throwingproviders` extensions.

Here's my current `module-info.java`:

`

```
module com.example.mymodule {

    requires com.google.guice;
    requires com.google.guice.extensions.assistedinject;
    requires com.google.guice.extensions.throwingproviders;

    //...
}


`
```

The application is based on Maven and when I run `mvn package` I get no error. But In Eclipse (2018-12), I have this error "`The package com.google.inject is accessible from more than one module":

[image: error]

[image]

I tried commenting each of the required module in `module-info.java` but I clearly need the three of them.

Is there something I can do to remove this error? Or is this an Eclipse bug?

Here's my `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>example</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.26</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice-throwingproviders</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice-assistedinject</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>11</source>
                        <target>11</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Here is a [minimal project](https://github.com/electrotype/modules-eclipse-issue) to reproduce my error.

And here's [a video of the issue](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J9DYqMUrxbs&feature=youtu.be) (to be watched in 1080P for clarity!).

Comment: Can you show the pom.xml contents?

Comment: @nitind `pom.xml` added, thank you.

Comment: Can you post more about how your Eclipse project is set up? I'd check if you've added Guice as a User Library (etc) there. If so, Eclipse might see Guice on the classpath it manages and also the classpath that it gets from Maven. If they both specified Guice, Eclipse might determine that you're getting Guice from more than one module, and that same error wouldn't appear when running `mvn` alone.

Comment: @JeffBowman - I added a minimal project to reproduce the issue and a video of it! Thanks for your help.

Comment: @nitind Please look at my new update. Thanks!

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue in a preview version of Eclipse 2019-03. Can you reproduce it in [M3](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2019-03/m3)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eclipse uses its own compiler which is even stricter than javac in following the specs. You are requiring different Modules/Jars in your module-info which are all using the package com.google.inject. This is some kind of a split package situation which is not allowed in the JPMS spec. AFAIK javac only yields an error if there are actual classes in the same packages of different moduls, but the eclipse compiler is even more picky here.

There are some solutions out there for solving split package problems. If you don't find a newer version of the libs where the problem is solved (which unfortunately is not very likely for most dependencies today) you could f.e. merge the modules into one custom modules, but this is not a perfect solution of course.

For more background information on the issue see also 
[Eclipse can't find XML related classes after switching build path to JDK 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51094274/eclipse-cant-find-xml-related-classes-after-switching-build-path-to-jdk-10) and https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8215739

Comment: I think your answer is the correct one. The problem is a false split packages error, which is not handle properly  in Eclipse 2018-12.

Answer (score 2):

I can reproduce the error on my machine (same Eclipse version, OpenJDK 11), works fine on Apache NetBeans IDE 10.0.

Seems to be a bug in Eclipse, you should file it [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=JDT). You already have a minimal project that reproduces the error, that helps a lot.

Comment: Done, thanks for the suggestion. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=545189  I guess your answer is the best I'll get here... The bounty will be yours if it's the case.

Comment: You could link back to this question from the bug. If someone there can confirm it's a bug (or even fix it), they should get the bounty.

Answer (score 2):

Your test project already works in RC2 of 4.11 (which will be released on March 20, 2019)

You can download the release candidate at https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/S-4.11RC2-201903070500/

Comment: I confirm that using a newer version of Eclipse works!

Answer (score 0):

Better way to deal with this kind of problem by just go to dependencies hierarchy in pom.xml, where you can find duplicate jar, sometimes it could be difficult to find duplicate jar as jar itself have pom dependencies and "Dependencies hierarchy" will help you to deal with maven problem
`[image]