# Migrating from JDK 8 to OPEN JDK 11 - Missing imports

Tags: java, import, java-11

I am trying to migrate my application from Java 8 to Open JDK 11.

In which few of the imports are missing in JDK 11. For example I could not find below imports

```
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xpath.regex.ParseException;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
```

But when i tired to add external jar for (w3c-dom.jar), we are getting the below error

**The package org.w3c.dom is accessible from more than one module: , java.xml**

As like the above, same error is occurring for all the imports

**The package org.xml.sax is accessible from more than one module: , java.xml**

Please suggest your views on the above error.

Comment: Are you using eclipse , if yes pls refer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51094274/eclipse-cant-find-xml-related-classes-after-switching-build-path-to-jdk-10/51094559 and https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=544758

Comment: Yes Ramesh, I am using Eclipse IDE. I have tried changing the JRE order in the class path but no luck.

Comment: In addition, I have tried using "xml-apis-2.0.jar" and my JDK is in the top of the classpath.

Comment: Seems it is a bug in the eclipse. Here is a long discussion about the bug - https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=536928

Comment: Thanks Ramesh. I am currently using eclipse Version: 2019-03 (4.11.0). Let me try for other version

Answer (score 4):

I faced similar issue, like mentioned below.

```
The package org.w3c.dom is accessible from more than one module: <unnamed>, java.xml.
```

Because there was a dependency which internally generating **xml-apis.jar**, and this jar was actually created the problem. I followed below mentioned steps and it helped me.

- Go to .m2 repository folder of your system and check if
  **xml-apis.jar** is present, if yes it means this jar is creating problem.
- Delete this jar from repository folder.
- And exclude the **xml-apis** transitive dependency in your pom.xml.
- Refresh, recompile project and check.

**Note**: It may be a different dependency in your case which generates this xml-api.jar, so find that dependency and exclude xm-api.

[image]