# Package is accessible from more than one module

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8, package, java-12

My project works fine with Java 1.8u151. I am trying to upgrade it to Java 12 but I am getting the following error.

```
Package is accessible from more than one module <unnamed>
```

This is the only error and is repeated with most packages in Java 12 but works fine with Java 8.

I have tried moving all jar files to classpath from module-path. Only Java 12 libraries in module-path. I rried to look for anything deprecated in packages with Java versions. I tried 3 different systems with different Java versions (all running OS-X 10.13.6, 10.13.3 10.11.6 and my own system 10.14.6).

Error Screenshot - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GS_v4rWe5wtigHIDeYtqd2r9YmTVyXbd

Errors are same with "org.w3c.dom" & "org.xml.sax" - package being called from `<unnamed>` and java.xml

The best solution would be to remove the problem or a way to guide the compiler to use JRE System Libraries only.

Comment: This question has been marked as a duplicate of the wrong question. It's not an Eclipse bug but a limitation of Java 9 and higher: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53824670/6505250

Comment: It looks like you have a dependency containing the same classes as the system library (which is not allowed in Java 9 and higher). In this case, just remove the dependency to fix the error.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Not an eclipse bug but a limitation of java 9 and above. @howlger please correct it if possible. Thanks!!

Comment: I'm voted to reopen, so it can be closed again as duplicate of the right question. I have not enough reputation to change it by my own. You might add a note to the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Eclipse can't find XML related classes after switching build path to JDK 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51094274/eclipse-cant-find-xml-related-classes-after-switching-build-path-to-jdk-10)

Answer (score -1):

Looks like bug in eclipse [Bug 546315 - [11] "The package [...] is accessible from more than one module:](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=546315)

Try to use latest version to fix this issue.

Comment: That is not about a subpacke like in the Eclipse bug that you referenced in your answer. It is a limitation of Java 9 and higher: two modules must not use the same package name. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/53824670/6505250

Answer (score -1):

There's a [bug in Eclipse](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=546315) which is not fully fixed. You may want to report your way of reproducing bug, if you find exact bug reproduction steps.

Comment: The referenced bug is fully fixed. In this case here, no subpackage is involved. But in Java 9 and higher two modules must not use the same package. See my comment above.