# Error using xml libraries inside gradle plugin with java 11

Tags: eclipse, gradle-plugin, java-module

I have created a new gradle plugin project with `gradle init` (gradle version 6.1):

1. Select type of project to generate:

   - Gradle plugin
2. Select implementation language:

   - Java
3. Select build script DSL:

   - Groovy

Then in **Eclipse version 2019-09 R (4.13.0)** running with **openjdk 11.0.5** I have imported this project as an "existing gradle project".

This project compiles without errors from the command line (`gradle build`) and also within Eclipse.

Now I add the following line to the source of the created plugin class:

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
```

From the command line this compiles without errors again. But Eclipse produces the error message:

```
The package javax.xml.parsers is accessible from more than one module: <unnamed>, java.xml
```

The second source for package `javax.xml.parsers` seems to be `gradle-api-6.1.jar`, that is automatically included when applying the `gradle-plugin`-Plugin.

I tried the suggested solutions from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53824670), but they don't seem to work for the development of a gradle-plugin.

**What can I do to make the Eclipse problems go away?**

Answer (score 2):

I found [this gradle issue](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/5835). It seems that gradle plugins are not java 11 ready yet. I'll try switching back to java 8 for gradle plugin development.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's a [gradle issue](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/12047). Works fine from command line and in IDEA but that's because of a [JDK bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8215739). Also check this [eclipse bug discussion](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=536928#c32).