# Update existing Spring Boot project from java 1.8 to java 11

Tags: java, eclipse, java-11, java-module, spring-boot-maven-plugin

Materialised fully functional Spring Boot application code from repository and  working fine with java 1.8. While upgrading to Java 11 got errors like some packages is accessible from more than one module

1.`The package javax.xml.parsers is accessible from more than one module: <unnamed>, java.xml`

2.`The package org.xml.sax is accessible from more than one module: <unnamed>, java.xml`

Tried to resolve the issue by restrict dependency using methods provided in the below links but not helped.

1. [Eclipse can't find XML related classes after switching build path to JDK 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51094274/eclipse-cant-find-xml-related-classes-after-switching-build-path-to-jdk-10/53824670#53824670)
2. https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.8/jdt.php#Java9

[Setting Eclipse JRE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPd0U.png)

[Setting Java Version in POM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrAmC.png)

[Setting Sping Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bfqn.png)

[Archiva dependency integrated to Spring Boot as rootParent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCeo0.png)

[Error While upgrading to java 11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w268W.png)

[Build path of migrated project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7U7O4.png)

Comment: Really tough with those links to images of what you've done. Try explaining with an [edit to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63018710/edit) what have you achieved and what errors have you faced then.

Comment: Have you tried out a fresh and simple spring boot application as shown in https://spring.io/quickstart with your Java 11 + Eclipse setup? So you could easily check if your origin project settings/code or your setup makes problems.

Comment: @de-jcup : Yeah , i have tried and working fine. when i try to migrate existing java 8 project to java 11  i have got the issue. it says that  ** package javax.xml.parsers is accessible from more than one module **

Comment: @Naman: I have tried to upgrade existing full functional Spring Boot application to Java 11 From java 8.While upgrading met with some issues.

1. The package javax.xml.parsers is accessible from more than one module: <unnamed>, java.xml
2.The package org.w3c.dom is accessible from more than one module: <unnamed>, java.xml

Followed above 2 link to resolve the issue . which is controlling dependency with modularity but failed.images above is specified to show how i setup JREJAVA VERSION,and POM FILE. and what was the error is specified in **Error With Upgrading to java 11**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason : Conflict between  `xml.apis` and  `java.xml`.due to the modularity concept in java

Solution : Excluded  `xml.apis` dependency in maven pom file.