# How to resolve conflict between JPMS and OSGi Bundle for Eclipse plugin project an Tycho

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, osgi, tycho, java-platform-module-system

I am working on an Eclipse based project that recently switched from Java 1.8 to Java 11. Due to that we have now a conflict between classes from the JRE and classes that are introduced from Eclipse plugin dependencies.

```
The package javax.xml.parsers is accessible from more than one module: <unnamed>, java.xml
```

So the java.xml.* classes are now present twice. once from the module java.xml and once due to a dependency from our plugin to org.eclipse.wst.xml.core

```
org.eclipse.wst.xml.core -> org.apache.xerces -> javax.xml
```

What I would like to do is exclude the module java.xml or the bundle javax.xml from being included in the build. I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51094274/eclipse-cant-find-xml-related-classes-after-switching-build-path-to-jdk-10/53824670#53824670) with an explanation on how to exclude the module but for multiple reasons I can't do it like this:

- many other modules depend on java.xml. removing this creates even more issues
- The mavan tycho build sees not to care what I do with the eclipse project module settings.

At this point I think the best solution is to exclude javax.xml from being included in the build but I was unable to find a way how to do this inside eclipse and for the tycho build.

Does anyone know how to exclude a dependency to a plugin from Eclipse build/Tycho build? Or is there another way to resolve module/osgi conflicts like this?

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you face this issue because `org.eclipse.wst.xml.core` uses Xerces in a version that is not yet ready for Java 9 or higher, and unfortunately also [reexports this dependency](https://git.eclipse.org/c/sourceediting/webtools.sourceediting.git/tree/xml/bundles/org.eclipse.wst.xml.core/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF#n313). Then the right thing would be in `org.eclipse.wst.xml.core` to update Xerces to [2.12.1](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/releases.html), right? I guess Eclipse WTP would welcome such a contribution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @howlger . With your information, i was able to implement a quick fix by building xerces 2.12 as a plug-in and using it in the build. of course, fixing the issue in `org.eclipse.wst.xml.core` would be better for everyone. I will see what i can do regarding this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the **root cause** is that `org.eclipse.wst.xml.core` uses **Xerces in a version that is not yet ready for Java 9 or higher** and that it [reexports this dependency](https://git.eclipse.org/c/sourceediting/webtools.sourceediting.git/tree/xml/bundles/org.eclipse.wst.xml.core/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF?id=e461e1370b24bc984cbb93252b5a609ecd50b736#n313).

According to the [release notes of **Xerces**](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/releases.html) at least version **2.12.1** (which is currently the latest version) is required for Java 9 or higher:

> Xerces-J was previously not building from sources when Java 9+ was
> used. This release fixes this.

In [Eclipse Orbit](https://www.eclipse.org/orbit/) (where you can get third-party plugins that are approved to be used also in commercial products) is the latest version of Xerces 2.9.0. So you have to **create a Xerces 2.12.1 plugin** yourself. It would be nice if you could contribute this work to Eclipse (to do so, [report it to Eclipse WTP Source Editing](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=WTP%20Source%20Editing)).

Comment: I reported https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=566183