# Eclipse error: The package javax.xml.namespace is accessible from more than one module: <unnamed>, java.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, java-11, openjdk-11

I have a maven multi-project build, just upgraded from java-8 to java-11
and got it working all fine, when building from maven command-line with jdk-11.

However, in Eclipse, I get tons of these errors, like:

```
  The package javax.xml.namespace is accessible from more than one module: <unnamed>, java.xml
```

I get same error-complaint on several `javax.xml.*, org.xml.*, and org.w3c.*` packages.

**Yes** (***before*** *you flag this post as "duplicate"*), there **are** other posts on SO on this issue, with some suggested (all non-trivial) solutions.

But, what I **still don't understand**, are these...

- How can this error pop-up *only* in Eclipse, when it builds OK with JDK11 from command-line?
- Is there a bug in Eclipse-compiler?
- Is there a bug in OpenJDK-11 compiler?

*They cannot both be correct*, when one says "OK", and the other throws out everything as "ERROR", can they?

What does the Java-11 spec actually say?

**EDIT:**

```
Eclipse version is 2020-12.
JDK is OpenJDK 11.0.9.1
```

Eclipse flags these errors whenever you try use those packages, for example:

```
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
```

Comment: do mention the Eclipse version, and comparing the equivalent command lines of what works and what doesn't(from eclipse) might help.

Comment: It's a confirmed bug of `javac`: see first item of the _EDITs_ section in https://stackoverflow.com/a/53824670/6505250

Comment: You could find everything in Stephan Herrmann's answer to the duplicate: a detailed explanation, links to the spec that is violated here, and a link to the bug that has not yet been fixed.

Comment: Thanks Howlger! --- Perfect answer. I read several articles on this issue, but that one did not show up high for me :(

Comment: Just realized, it's gonna be "fun", when they finally fix this bug in javac, and the whole swarm of intellij users also get hit by this sh*t-storm ;) --- it's now several days of work for me, to fix a non-trivial SOAP & legacy + spring-boot project --- I started with 7000+ errors in eclipse.... oh well.... :/