# Java9 module error only in Eclipse (not IntelliJ/Gradle)

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, java-9

I am getting a `The package javax.xml.namespace is accessible from more than one module: <unnamed>, java.xml` when trying to upgrade an app from Java8 -> 11.

The error, as well as potential solutions are well documented.

So my question is: Why do I only get this error in Eclipse/Buildship, whereas my team mates don't see anything in IntelliJ, and the Gradle build isn't affected either.

How is it that these module errors seem to be unavoidable in Eclipse, yet IntelliJ/Gradle can skip them altogether. Isn't this a restriction of the Java9 module system that should apply to any build tool?

Comment: It does appear the error is legit though. I have found the duplicate package, and removing it clears the error, so as far as I can tell Gradle should be reporting it too.

Comment: @Slaw Nope, it's a [confirmed bug of javac](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53824670/6505250).