# javax.xml.rpc.Service - not present in JDK 11?

Tags: java, java-8, java-11, java-platform-module-system

I am migrating a legacy Java 8 project to Java 11.
The project is using this class `javax.xml.rpc.Service`
It was being picked up from a library/jar before (I mean in Java 8): `jaxrpc.jar`

But since I'm migrating to Java 11, and I must comply with the requirement of "unique visibility"
( see https://stackoverflow.com/a/53824670/2300597 ),
I had to remove the JAR that contains this class `javax.xml.rpc.Service` (`jaxrpc.jar`) from my project... because now (in Java 11, in fact it's since Java 9) **only one module must provide/expose the `javax.xml.rpc` package**. But I don't think this `Service` class is in the JDK.

So how do I solve this?

I still need `javax.xml.rpc.Service` but I cannot use the jar this class is in. I seem to be stuck here.

Btw, I have the same issue with `javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException`

What is the right way to solve such issues?

Comment: Does [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43574427/642706) help?

Comment: @BasilBourque Not really, it doesn't talk about the package I have in my question. I found a workaround though - I just patched the jaxrpc.jar by removing the `javax.xml.namespace` from it, and putting the patched version back in my project (this way I kept the  `javax.xml.rpc` package). Seems `javax.xml.namespace` was the only package that was clashing with JDK provided packages (from the system modules). I wonder if that's the right solution though - just doing a surgery on the JAR, really?!

Comment: @BasilBourque Why didn't they migrate javax.xml.rpc also into the JDK ?! That's weird. And the other thing is: jaxrpc.jar has no recent version. So... one is left only with the surgery option, I think.

Answer (score 8):

The new maven coordinates for JAXRPC are here.

https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jakarta_EE_Maven_Coordinates

Specifically,

```
<groupId>jakarta.xml.rpc</groupId>
<artifactId>jakarta.xml.rpc-api</artifactId>
```

I assume this might get you closer to something that works. However, this may not really be enough for you. JAX-RPC became JAX-WS a long time ago.

---

Some of the [Jakarta EE specifications](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/) may be of interest to you:

- [Jakarta XML RPC](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/xml-rpc/)
- [Jakarta XML Binding](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/xml-binding/)
- [Jakarta XML Registries](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/xml-registries/)
- [Jakarta XML Web Services Specification](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/xml-web-services/)
- [Jakarta Web Services Metadata](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/web-services-metadata/)
- [Jakarta SOAP with Attachments](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/soap-attachments/)
- [Jakarta RESTful Web Services](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/restful-ws/)

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look. At least I have some workaround now after patching the jar.