# The package org.xml.sax is accessible from more than one module: <unnamed>, java.xml

Tags: eclipse-plugin, java-11

We have eclipse plugins written long back. The compliance level was java.1.8. Now I have changed it to java 11. We are using and. While building, I am getting below error:

The package org.xml.sax is accessible from more than one module: , java.xml

can anyone please help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Eclipse can't find XML related classes after switching build path to JDK 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51094274/eclipse-cant-find-xml-related-classes-after-switching-build-path-to-jdk-10)

Comment: We have our custom eclipse plugins which were written in 1.6. Now want to migrate it to java 11. I have tried to use module-info.java but there were eclipse plugins and other jars which are not modularized sofe facing issues

Comment: In the Java Platform Module System which is enabled by having `module-info.java` file modules are resolved at compile time. In contrast, in Eclipse/OSGi bundles/plugins can be started and stopped at run time. Since Java 9 it became illegal to use the same package in different modules. The system library consists of modules, which cannot be changed and by not using the Java Platform Module System every thing else is in the unnamed module. Or with other words, you need to get rid of the packages that are also in the system library to be able to upgrade to Java 9 or higher.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the JDK version back to 1.8 helps me.