# how to set the compiler option --patch-modules in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, java-platform-module-system

I am using JDK 19 in a modular maven project.
My project compiles in the shell, but I get errors in Eclipse.

```
The package org.slf4j is accessible from more than one module: <unnamed>, org.slf4j
```

The following compiler args work with maven in the shell.

```xml
<compilerArgs>
    <arg>--patch-module</arg>
    <arg>org.slf4j=${settings.localRepository}/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/2.0.6/slf4j-api-2.0.6.jar</arg>
</compilerArgs>
```

How can I teach Eclipse also to use these args?

Comment: Eclipse uses its own compiler with different arguments.

Comment: `--patch-module` does not make sense here. Learn what the error message `The package ... is accessible from more than one module: ...` means and then fix it even though `javac` does not show it.

Comment: Is the list of modules literally “, org.slf4j”? Assuming that the empty string refers to the unnamed module, you just have to remove slf4j from the class path.

Comment: @Holger It's not an empty string. It's `<unnamed>` not formatted as _Code Sample_. `--patch-module` is misused here to "patch" a Maven dependency. Maybe trial and error resulted in this "creative" solution.

Comment: @howlger so my assumption was correct, slf4j has been placed on the class path and the module path.

Comment: @Holger Right, and as you say, removing the JAR from the classpath should solve what has been asked. But the main problem here seems to be the `--patch-module` hack, which leads to a number of other problems that the OP is probably not yet aware of (running it from inside an IDE, updating dependencies, issues in projects that depend on this project, etc.). The question is an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), asking for X instead of a correct solution for Y unknown to us (Y was the reason why the `--patch-module` hack was made).

Comment: Hello,
thanks for your answers.
Normally i would say you are right, but maven-embedder uses org.slf4j package to access slf4j classes. 
I cannot exclude it from the build.

Comment: How is the Maven Embedder related to this? A web search for `maven embedder "--patch-module"` gives me no hits. Please explain with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) what made you misuse `--patch-module`?

Comment: Hello,
maven-embedder comes trough the quarkus archetype.
I cannot exclude the artifact.
Unfortunately the pom is too large to post it.

Comment: That still doesn't explain why you are misusing `--patch-module` here. You were not asked for the full `pom.xml` or parts of it, but to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which is a complete `pom.xml` as minimal as possible to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Hello,
i published a project to reproduce the problem at
https://github.com/hw-4/testproject

btw - patch-module is just a workaround. The base problem is 
The package org.slf4j is accessible from more than one module.

Comment: If the error is shown only with `--patch-module`, then `--patch-module` is your base problem. Otherwise you should track the issue down to the two dependencies that causing it, e.g. in the Maven POM editor, tab _Dependency Hierarchy_. For details about the error, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/53824670/6505250

Comment: Please forget the patch-module thing.
Let's come back to the original Question - How to set a compiler option in eclipse.