How to solve the import in jdk17 version javax.mail. XML. The transform. The Source module conflic
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import javax.xml.validation.Schema;
import javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory;
import javax.xml.validation.Validator;

The project is based on the plug-in project before Java 9, which uses some subclasses of javax xml. The eclipse version now in use is 2022-03 jdk17. When the plug-in project exports the generated executable file, the error is reported when clicking the Javax.xml function at the time of running.
    !ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2024-06-14 11:14:46.036
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
    java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The package javax.xml.transform is accessible from more than one module: <unnamed>, java.xml
    The package javax.xml.transform.stream is accessible from more than one module: <unnamed>, java.xml
    The package javax.xml.validation is accessible from more than one module: <unnamed>, java.xml
    The package javax.xml.validation is accessible from more than one module: <unnamed>, java.xml
    The package javax.xml.validation is accessible from more than one module: <unnamed>, java.xml

Cannot achieve this function, how to solve it？
I have seen a lot of workaround on the web, there are maven based changes corresponding to the pom.xml file, but this is an RCP plug-in project, does not use maven and mole-info.java, cannot solve this problem now

Show us the MANIFEST.MF of your plug-in. Note that [tag:tycho] is now the recommended way to build RCPs.

A module-info.java file does not make sense in an Eclipse plugins since it means using JPMS where modules cannot be started and stopped in contrast to OSGi (which is used by Eclipse). The package javax.xml is contained in the system library and since Java 9 the same package must not be accessible from more than one module (if not using JPMS, <unnamed> is everything that is not in the system library). Get rid of  the duplicate javax.xml package(s) outside of the system library. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/53824670/6505250

Can't you use the export eclipse product that comes with eclipse?

With Tycho you can do more and it makes maintenance easier. Therefore, Tycho is the recommended way nowadays. The Eclipse IDE packages are also built with Tycho.
