# Testcase is getting failed if run through POM.xml?

Tags: maven, selenium, junit, selenium-webdriver, pom.xml

If I run my test through suite they are running, but If I run the same same testcases through POM.xml I got the below error, Can any one explain me what's wrong with my code?

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
parallel='none', perCoreThreadCount=true, threadCount=2, useUnlimitedThreads=false
Running com.example.jacoco.ERPLogin
This is Before class method
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.318 sec <<< FAILURE!
test(com.example.jacoco.ERPLogin)  Time elapsed: 0.006 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/ElementTraversal
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:276)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:319)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:620)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:260)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:195)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:276)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:319)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractDOMParser.startDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.startEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.startDocumentParsing(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:208)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.FileExtension.readIdFromInstallRdf(FileExtension.java:97)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.FileExtension.writeTo(FileExtension.java:60)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.ClasspathExtension.writeTo(ClasspathExtension.java:63)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile.installExtensions(FirefoxProfile.java:416)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile.layoutOnDisk(FirefoxProfile.java:394)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:89)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:246)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:114)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:191)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:186)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:182)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:95)
    at com.example.jacoco.ERPLogin.<init>(ERPLogin.java:16)
```

and my POM.xml is as follows,

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>MyGroup</groupId>
  <artifactId>TestCodeCoverage</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>MyMavenProject</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

<build>
<pluginManagement>
<plugins>


     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.5.5.201112152213</version>
        <configuration>
            <destFile>${basedir}/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-unit.exec</destFile>
            <dataFile>${basedir}/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-unit.exec</dataFile>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>jacoco-initialize</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>jacoco-site</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>report</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>


    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.5</source>
            <target>1.5</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

      <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>integration-test</goal>
            <goal>verify</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.14.1</version>

     <dependencies>
     <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
      <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
      <version>2.12</version>   
       </dependency>
    </dependencies>

     <configuration>                     
        <includes>
            <include>**/*.class</include>
         </includes>
        </configuration>    
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
   </pluginManagement>
  </build>



     <dependencies>

       <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.17</version>
        <type>maven-plugin</type>
       </dependency>  

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
      <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
      <version>6.8</version>
    </dependency> 

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
      <version>2.41.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
      <version>2.41.0</version>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <type>maven-plugin</type>
    </dependency> 

  </dependencies>

 <dependencyManagement>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.opera</groupId>
                    <artifactId>operadriver</artifactId>
                    <version>1.5</version>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                            <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
 </dependencyManagement> 

    <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <configuration>
          <!-- <outputName>GoogleSearchTestResults</outputName>      -->
           <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/site</outputDirectory>             
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>  

</project>
```

Comment: I suppose the clue is `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/ElementTraversal`

Comment: Yes, Why am I getting this error?

Comment: It can't load class `ElementTraversal`. From which library did you get this class? Add needed dependency to your pom.xml.

Comment: Which dependency should I need to add ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10234201/appengine-error-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-w3c-dom-elementtraversal