# org.testng.TestNGException: An error occurred while instantiating class

Tags: java, maven, selenium, testng

My selenium automation framework using TestNG is working fine on the windows 7 but when I configured the same framework on the windows 10 I'm facing the below issue.
Could you please help me on the same.

**Test Details:**

**Operating system:** windows 10 64 bit

**Eclipse Version:** Version: 2019-03 (4.11.0)

**TestNG version:** 6.14.3

> [RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.3
>   org.testng.TestNGException:  An error occurred while instantiating
>   class com.saf.aw_nxt_end_to_end_tests.AW_NXT_Login:
>   org/w3c/dom/ElementTraversal  at
>   org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance1(ClassHelper.java:435)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance(ClassHelper.java:336)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getDefaultInstance(ClassImpl.java:125)
>     at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getInstances(ClassImpl.java:190)   at
>   org.testng.internal.TestNGClassFinder.processFactory(TestNGClassFinder.java:203)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestNGClassFinder.processMethod(TestNGClassFinder.java:179)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestNGClassFinder.processClass(TestNGClassFinder.java:171)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestNGClassFinder.(TestNGClassFinder.java:121)
>     at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:370)   at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:271)   at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:241)   at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.(TestRunner.java:192)     at
>   org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_12$1.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_12.java:33)
>     at
>   org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_12$DelegatingTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG6_12.java:66)
>     at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner$ProxyTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:713)
>     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:260)    at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.(SuiteRunner.java:198)   at
>   org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1295)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1273)    at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1128)  at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)   at
>   org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77) Caused
>   by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/ElementTraversal  at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)   at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     at
>   org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractDOMParser.startDocument(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startDocument(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.startEntity(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.startDocumentParsing(Unknown
>   Source)   at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown
>   Source)   at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown
>   Source)   at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
>     at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)  at
>   javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:205)     at
>   org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator$1.parse(DOMConfigurator.java:749)
>     at
>   org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:871)
>     at
>   org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:755)
>     at
>   org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.configure(DOMConfigurator.java:896)
>     at com.saf.utilities.Log.getInstance(Log.java:19)   at
>   com.saf.base.BaseTest.(BaseTest.java:138)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:24)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance1(ClassHelper.java:423)
>     ... 24 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.w3c.dom.ElementTraversal  at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     ... 58 more
>   Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -agentlib:jvmhook Picked up
>   _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xrunjvmhook -Xbootclasspath/a:"C:\Program Files (x86)\HP\Unified Functional
>   Testing\bin\java_shared\classes";"C:\Program Files (x86)\HP\Unified
>   Functional Testing\bin\java_shared\classes\jasmine.jar"

Comment: Are you using maven? or copied the jars manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are getting the `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/ElementTraversal` error.

From [Another Answer:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10234201/appengine-error-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-w3c-dom-elementtraversal/15197808#15197808)
The reason for this error is that the 1.4.01 version of the xml-apis library, includes the required ElementTraversal class. Other versions like 2.0.0, 1.0.0, etc. do not include it, and the application fails while compiling.

- **MAVEN SOLUTION:**

At pom.xml , set "xml-apis" dependency to version 1.4.01:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.01</version>
</dependency>
```

- **SOLUTION FOR EVERYONE ELSE:**

If not using maven, you can manually add the xml-apis library, version 1.4.01. You will find the jars inside the xml-commons binary package, named "XML Commons External 1.4.01", and you can download it here: http://xerces.apache.org/mirrors.cgi.

Finally, compile and execute your java application/project with this version of the library.

Comment: After adding the mentioned maven dependency. I was able to run the framework successfully. @S ahmed thanks for the answer :)